# Permissions set to Add, Edit, View but not delete...but users can't edit

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions

I set permissions levels for a group to Add, Edit, View but Not Delete.  The only thing is they can't edit it now.  The users click on Edit in a SharePoint list item and they get access denied page.  Not sure what happened.

Comment: Look under List Settings > Advanced Settings > Item-Level Permissions > Create and Edit Access. If this is set to "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" instead of "create and edit all items" your non-Full Control users will get an access denied error when trying to edit a list item they did not create. If this isn't the issue, it might be a problem with the permission level itself. What version of SharePoint are you running?

Comment: I now see in one of your other recent posts this Add Edit View permission level is one you created. My best guess is that something in that custom permission level is not properly configured. Can you provide one or more screenshots showing how you have this AEV level set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same permission level. I named it ContributeNonDelete.
And it works as expected.

Be sure that following checkbox are checked in your permission level:

**List Permissions**

- Add Items
- Edit Items
- View Items
- Open Items
- View Versions
- Delete Versions
- Create Alerts
- View Application Pages

**Site Permissions**

- Browse Directories
- Use Self-Service Site Creation
- View Pages Browse
- User Information
- Use Remote Interfaces
- Use Client Integration Features
- Open
- Edit Personal User Information

**Personal Permissions**

- Manage Personal Views
- Add/Remove Personal Web Parts
- Update Personal Web Parts

Comment: Thanks, @raf, I tested this out on my SharePoint site and came to same conclusion.  The only thing different from yours was I unchecked Delete Versioning...I'm going to count your comment as my answer.  Thanks!